# My A* implementation is not correctly keeping track of the "camefrom" map

Tags: c++, a-star

I'm using the [Wikipedia article on A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2A_search_algorithm#Pseudocode). My implementation, when walking back through the `cameFrom` map, after finding a path from `0,0` to `7,0` keeps ping-ponging between `5,0` and `6,0`, as in the `cameFrom[5,0] == 6,0` and `cameFrom[6,0] == 5,0`.

```
typedef std::deque<birunji::utils::Vector2i> AStarPath;

AStarPath ReconstructPath(const Map& map,
                          std::map<std::size_t,birunji::utils::Vector2i>& cameFrom,
                          const birunji::utils::Vector2i& c,
                          const birunji::utils::Vector2i& start)
{
    AStarPath totalPath;
    birunji::utils::Vector2i current = c;
    totalPath.push_back(current);
    while(cameFrom.find(map.GetIndex(current)) != cameFrom.end() && current != start)
    {
        current = cameFrom[map.GetIndex(current)];
        totalPath.push_back(current);
    }
    return totalPath;
}

AStarPath AStar(
    const birunji::utils::Vector2i& start,
    const birunji::utils::Vector2i& goal,
    const Map& map)
{
    using namespace birunji::utils;

    std::set<Vector2i, std::function<bool(const Vector2i&, const Vector2i&)>> closed([](const Vector2i& a, const Vector2i& b)
    {
        return true;
    });

    std::map<std::size_t, float> fScore;
    float dx = std::abs(start.x - goal.x);
    float dy = std::abs(start.y - goal.y);
    float cost = 1.0f * (dx + dy) + (1.4f - 2.0f * 1.0f) * std::min(dx,dy);
    fScore[map.GetIndex(start)] = cost;

    std::set<Vector2i, std::function<bool(const Vector2i&,const Vector2i&)>> open([&](const Vector2i& a, const Vector2i& b)
    {
        return fScore[map.GetIndex(a)] < fScore[map.GetIndex(b)];
    });
    open.emplace(start);

    std::map<std::size_t,Vector2i> cameFrom;

    std::map<std::size_t,float> gScore;
    gScore[map.GetIndex(start)] = 0;

    while(!open.empty())
    {
        auto itr = open.begin();
        Vector2i current = *itr;
        open.erase(itr);

        if(current == goal)
            return ReconstructPath(map,cameFrom, current,start);

        closed.emplace(current);

        for(const TileData& n : map.GetNeighbours(current))
        {
            Vector2i neighbour(n.x,n.y);
            if(closed.count(neighbour))
                continue;

            float moveCost;
            if(!map.TraverseCost(current,neighbour,moveCost))
                continue;

            float tentativeGScore = gScore[map.GetIndex(current)] + moveCost;

            std::size_t neighbourIndex = map.GetIndex(neighbour);

            if(!open.count(neighbour))
                open.emplace(neighbour);
            else if(tentativeGScore >= gScore[neighbourIndex])
                continue;

            cameFrom[neighbourIndex] = current;
            gScore[neighbourIndex] = tentativeGScore;
            float dx = std::abs(neighbour.x - goal.x);
            float dy = std::abs(neighbour.y - goal.y);
            float h = 1.0f * (dx + dy) + (1.4f - 2.0f * 1.0f) * std::min(dx,dy);
            fScore[neighbourIndex] = tentativeGScore + h;
        }
    }
    return {};
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you haven't done it before, now seems to be a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It has probably nothing to do with your problem, but as heuristics I would suggest using squared Euler distance, i.e. `dist(a, b) = (b.x - a.x)^2 + (b.y - a.y)^2`. Real costs would then be 10 for walking horizontally or vertically and 14 for walking diagonally. Just a little easier to read and calculate.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a step missing in the Wiki, when you get the Neighbours you need to be updating their parent (came from) and g values based on the current path (if it is a better path than the neighbours existing path)

```
/* Can the neighbour's g value be improved by coming from this current node ? */
if(neighbour.g > (currentNode.g + ( currentNode.distanceTo(neighbour)*this.wg ))) {

    /* Yes this is a better path to the neighbour. Set neighbour g to the current node g + distance from current node */
    neighbour.g = currentNode.g + ( currentNode.distanceTo(neighbour)*this.wg );

    /* Parent node of neighbour is changed to the current node */
    neighbour.parent = currentNode;
}
```

Sorry, that is Javascript not C. But hopefully helps you get on track. Also notice how comments make it easier to read and dbug...

This is probably the best explanation of AStar (start at 6:00 for your exact issue) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-L-WgKMFuhE

My example in Javascript which has a nice visual step through.. http://mjp.co/js/astar/